# Django mixins for class-based-generic views

Tags: django, django-views, mixins

I am trying to implement staff_member_required mixins:

Here are the two ways I found on how to do so:

First:

```
class StaffRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            messages.error(
                request,
                'You do not have the permission required to perform the '
                'requested operation.')
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
        return super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request,
            *args, **kwargs)
```

Second:

```
class StaffRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        view = super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).as_view(*args, **kwargs)
        return staff_member_required(view)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            messages.error(
                request,
                'You do not have the permission required to perform the '
                'requested operation.')
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
        return super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request,
            *args, **kwargs)
```

What I want to know is:

1. Why the second way is overriding the `as_view()` method and wrapping it with `staff_member_required` ?
2. Do we get any 'additional' advantages by doing so ?

I am new to these mixins. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL; DR**: they're close to the same, the difference is in checking `is_active` as well as `is_staff` and the error `messages`. You probably don't need both because the `as_view` override negates the need for the `dispatch` override anyway.

These are really just two ways of doing *close* to the same thing.

This code:

```
class StaffRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        view = super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).as_view(*args, **kwargs)
        return staff_member_required(view)
```

...could actually be used alone to implement the [`staff_member_required` decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py). In this case the `staff_member_required` functionality gets called in the view's `as_view()` function (i.e., from `as_view()` in your URLConf).

This code:

```
class StaffRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            messages.error(
                request,
                'You do not have the permission required to perform the '
                'requested operation.')
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
        return super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request,
            *args, **kwargs)
```

...filters users in the `dispatch` method. You can see in the Django codebase that [`as_view` actually calls `dispatch`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L68). This means that if you use *both together* you won't actually ever trigger the `if not request.user.is_staff` code in the `dispatch` method because any user who doesn't pass would have been filtered out in the `as_view` method.

The second difference is that `staff_member_required` is slightly different from what the first code does. If you [check out the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py), you'll notice that `staff_member_required` also checks whether the user's `is_active` flag passes (not just `is_staff` like in your `dispatch` decorator). It also doesn't pass the `messages.error` like in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this has been answered and that my solution does not include all the details of the other one. But it's really simple and maybe it's all someone needs.

There goes the code:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class StaffMemberRequiredMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

That's enough to make the code block non privileged users and redirect to the `LOGIN_URL`.

I hope that helps.