# Django Classed based view __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to use class based views in Django!

my urls.py:

```
path('pie-chart/', views.pie_chart, name='pie_chart.html'),
```

my view.py

```
class pie_chart(View):
    def __init__(self, labels, data):
        self.labels = labels
        self.data = data


    def active_sessions(self, request):
        self.labels = []
        self.data = []
        queryset = Employees.objects.values('department__name').annotate(total_session=Count('employeeconnection__employeesession'))
        for item in queryset: 
            self.labels.append(item['department__name'])
            self.data.append(item['total_session'])

        return render(request, 'pie_chart.html', {
            'labels': self.labels,
            'data': self.data,
        })
```

I am getting This Error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Comment: First of all, you need to use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) in urls.py. Next question - what do you expect in `data` variable?

Comment: i have changed it to:     path('pie-chart/', pie_chart.as_view(), name='pie_chart'),  now i get this error; AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'.                  This data will be used to generate a chart(chartjs) so the data will be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly use `View` methods - set the handler method in view for GET requests:

```
class PieChart(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        labels = []
        data = []
        queryset = employees.objects.values('department__name').annotate(total_session=Count('employeeconnection__employeesession'))
        for item in queryset: 
            labels.append(item['department__name'])
            data.append(item['total_session'])
        return render(request, 'pie_chart.html', {
                'labels': labels,
                'data': data,
            })
```

Then call `as_view()` in urls.py:

```
path('pie-chart/', views.PieChart.as_view(), name='pie_chart.html'),
```

And you do not need to override view `__init__` method in order to receive parameters from request.

Comment: still this erro: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: @sansan show your imports in view. Do you imported generic view? - `from django.views import View`

Comment: I use @staff_member_required before function, I think this cause the problem

Comment: Yes, it can be applied to function based views, not class based views. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36650536/4996863) answer may be helpful.

Comment: I get this error: 'PieChart' object has no attribute 'labels'

Comment: Thanks! it worked! but how can i use the second method within the same class to return the second data the same time? That is why i am using class based view!

Comment: Which one (method) are you want to use? You can create as many methods as you like inside the CBV and call them from `get` handler depending on conditions/request data.

Comment: I want to have many charts in the same page. As now the first method (def get) will return pie_chart.html, how can I use one more method and return the html in one time. so i need to have data2 from the second method and return it in the same html.

Comment: That's another question that is hard to explain in single line comment, but general advice - use `TemplateView` and check for `get_template_names` method.

Answer (score 0):

When using class based views, you have to call `as_view` class method when registering this view in urls, instead of simply passing it to url:

```
path('pie-chart/', views.pie_chart.as_view(), name='pie_chart.html'),
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: Why your view is a function again? Please share full code and describe intent of requiring some parameters in `__init__` of your class. You can edit your question to provide that.